# Rewrite URL using .htaccess display 404

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a  `blog folder` and in the blog folder, I have 2 files. `index.php` and `post.php`. Index for display all articles I write and post.php to display details about all articles. My `.htaccess` file has this code:

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/blog/(.*)$ ^/blog/post.php?link=$1 [L]
```

In my `post.php` I have this code:

```
if(!empty($_GET['link'])) {
        $id = $_REQUEST['link'];
    }

    if (null === $id) {
        header('index');
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM blog WHERE link = :link";
        $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindParam(':link', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->execute();
        $project = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

In the database  `column link` have a value of `SEO URL`. The problem is when I open `example.com/blog/` I get all articles I write, but when I open a random article, I got a 404 error, what is wrong with my code?

**Note: if I change my `.htaccess` to this:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ blog/post.php?link=$1 [L]
```

Now when I open `example.com/blog/`I got a details page not a list of all my articles from the database and the SEO URL works. So `example.com/blog/` and `example.com/blog/random-article` are the same and that shouldn't be like that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `^blog/(.*)$` matches on the path of `example.com/blog/` as well, because the `*` quantifier allows for _zero_ matches as well. Make that `^blog/(.+)$` instead, to demand that there must be something after the slash.

Comment: The problem is the same. Sorry for the late answer. @CBroe